App fails to build with an error: 2 files found with path 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins
I tried building my app but it wouldn't build and show this error.
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction


2 files found with path 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins' from inputs:

  - C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1203ed0043761220f2e7b9faa528e635\transformed\jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.31.jar

  - C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a14ecf8d638c881bd231708fc869e941\transformed\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.6.0.jar

 Adding a packagingOptions block may help

Tried following the site they gave me to read info but the site ain't even there
Adding packagingoptions
Can't seem to get what it is
Ps. Am still new to this

You need to add a packagingOptions in your build.gradle file.
This block will handle the duplicate files during the build process.
android {

    .....

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins'
    }
}

